# Answer a phone call on the browser with Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am looking to answer a call through a worker on my browser.
On my workers, I have the following

```
{"contact_uri":"client:Peter"}
```

On my incoming call method, a task successfully created and get into the queue

```
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |response|
  response.say(message: message)
  response.enqueue workflowSid: 'sid'
end
render xml: twiml.to_xml
```

Then on my front end code, a reservation.created event is been fired.

```
worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(data.token)
worker.on 'reservation.created', (reservation) ->
  reservation.dequeue()
```

But the reservation.dequeue() is not initializing a call to my browser, I am still getting the Twilio default waiting sound and no other response.

Comment: `worker` is a WebWorker, correct? You might try using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) to send the result of `reservation.dequeue()` back to the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine as far as I can see but the main issue here is that you do not have Twilio client defined. If you are going to send those calls to browser than you need to setup a Twilio Client, you must also set up the devices. You can find more information on [Twilio Client documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript).

After generating a Twilio Client Token You can connect to Twilio i.e.

```js
device = new Twilio.Device(data.token, {
                closeProtection: true,
               debug: true,
                // Set Opus as our preferred codec. Opus generally performs better, requiring less bandwidth and
                // providing better audio quality in restrained network conditions. Opus will be default in 2.0.
                codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
                // Use fake DTMF tones client-side. Real tones are still sent to the other end of the call,
                // but the client-side DTMF tones are fake. This prevents the local mic capturing the DTMF tone
                // a second time and sending the tone twice. This will be default in 2.0.
                fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                // Use `enableRingingState` to enable the device to emit the `ringing`
                // state. The TwiML backend also needs to have the attribute
                // `answerOnBridge` also set to true in the `Dial` verb. This option
                // changes the behavior of the SDK to consider a call `ringing` starting
                // from the connection to the TwiML backend to when the recipient of
                // the `Dial` verb answers.
                enableRingingState: true
            });
            // Incoming call to.
             device.on('incoming', function (conn) {
             //This will automatically accept the call, bind it with a button to enhance it
                        conn.accept();         
                });
```

For more information on this go to [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#twilio-device)